# controller not returning json result to view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, jsonresult

I am trying to update a checkbox list by using jquery to listen for a change. For some reason it seems that the controller method is not returning the JSON.  I based this code on [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym).

In the example the controller calls `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`, but I could only get `return Json(data)` working. My theory is that the return type has to specifically allow GET, but I dont know how to get that working.

My code works fine, with no errors and all 3 console statements appear in the web browser.

my jquery code (in my view):

```
$('#lgcheese').change(function() {
    ddToPopulate.empty();
    console.log('change detected');
    $.getJSON(CoIdUrl, { CoName: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        console.log('in shit');
        if (!data) { console.log('no json returned');return;}
        ddToPopulate.append($('<ListItem></ListItem>').val('').text('Please select'));
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            ddToPopulate.append($('<ListItem></ListItem>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
        });
    });
});
```

later in my view I call: `<CheckBoxList ID="cheesebox"></CheckBoxList>` to create the checkbox list the jquery is supposed to populate.

My controller has method:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult FetchCoIds(string CoName)
{
   var data = new { Value = "val", Text = CoName+"_val1" };
   return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: You need to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. I don't see how it would ever work without it when using a GET request...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I cant add that because my using statements are wrong (I think) but I cant figure out the correct ones

Comment: I've usually just use `IActionResult` and then just `return new { .... }`.  It will return as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your action method with behavior. Try this

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FetchCoIds(string CoName)
    {
        var data = new { Value = "val", Text = CoName+"_val1" };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Note:this answer is applicable for asp.net MVC not for Core**

Comment: JsonRequestBehavior Doesnt exist in my current context

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that but unfortunately got: `JsonResult does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

Comment: let me know full qualified class name of JsonResult you are using

Comment: the json class is from: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168340/discussion-between-user9405863-and-rilcon42).

Comment: No need for all that, just use `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @Rilcon42 which framework you are using Core or webMVC?